# How to measure the webpage loading time in safari browser on iOS device

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, web, mobile-safari

I have a website for mobile devices, and want to know how long it takes for the browser to open it and render it. On a desktop, we can use many developer tools(Firebug, Chrome/IE developer tool) to check such information, but on a browser on an iPhone, seems that no such plugin can do it yet.

In short, I want to know when it sends DOM content loaded event and page load event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use desktop Safari on OS-X to debug Mobile Safari and you get all the Timeline tools. See [the Safari Web Inspector Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/safari-developer/devcbd090540/mac).

You can also debug Android Chrome (but *not* the old Android Browser) with desktop Chrome. See [Remote Debugging Chrome on Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).

Comment: BTW, if I want to design an iphone app to do this monitoring, is it possible? such as open the app and input web address, the app can call   safari's function to request and render the webpage, so that i can monitor the page load event in the app. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

That's not trivially done: the debugger interface is exposed through the USB connection. You can debug an embedded UIWebView through the debugger though, which you can drive easier yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i add another thread for this added question, hope you can reply, LOL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808631/how-to-implement-an-ios-http-sniffer-app-like-httpwatch